# Passing 2 Parameter In 2 Different Checkbox Into A Function

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" checked ="checked" value="1" onclick = "a()"/>
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" checked ="checked" value="2" onclick = "a()"/>

function(checkbox1,checkbox2)
{ 
   if(checkbox1.checked == true && checkbox2.checked == false)
   {
     alert("checkbox1 is checked, Checkbox2 ix Unchecked");
   }
}
```

how can i pass the checkbox1 and checkbox2 value in a()???

Answer (score 2):

You can just grab it using :

```
var mycheckbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
```

and

```
var mycheckbox2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');
```

You might want to change your checkbox2's id to id='checkbox2' having non-unique id is not valid syntax.

If you were asking to modify the function you posted then it's the following:

```
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" checked ="checked" value="1" onclick = "a()"/>
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox2" checked ="checked" value="2" onclick = "a()"/>

function a(){
     var mycheckbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
     var mycheckbox2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');
     if(mycheckbox1.checked && !checkbox2.checked)
          alert('checkbox1 is checked, checkbox2 is unchecked');
}
```

Now if you were asking to get the value of the checkbox that is checked then it's the following:

```
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" checked ="checked" value="1" onclick = "a(this)"/>
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox2" checked ="checked" value="2" onclick = "a(this)"/>

function a(box){
    if(box.checked)
      alert(box.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that gets all checkboxes in the form and displays their value and state

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" checked ="checked" value="1" onclick = "a()"/>
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox2" checked ="checked" value="2" onclick = "a()"/>
</form>
<script>
function a(){
    form = document.getElementById("myForm")
    str = ""
for (i=0;i<form.elements.length;i++) {
    type = form.elements[i].type
     if (type=="checkbox") {
            str += "\n"
        str += (form.elements[i].checked)? form.elements[i].id + " is checked " : form.elements[i].id + " is unchecked ";
        str += "\n"
        str +=  form.elements[i].id + " value is  "+ form.elements[i].value;
     }


}
    alert(str);
}
</script>
```

If you want just individual values /state see below
For value

```
 <input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" checked ="checked" value="1" onclick = "a(this.value)"/>
    <input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" checked ="checked" value="2" onclick = "a(this.value)"/>
    <script>
    function a(v){
        alert(v)
    }
    </script>
```

For checked/unchecked state

```
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" checked ="checked" value="1" onclick = "a(this.checked)"/>
<input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" checked ="checked" value="2" onclick = "a(this.checked)"/>
<script>
function a(v){
    alert(v)
}
</script>
```

Comment: That will be the value, not the checked state.

Comment: The question states "how can I pass the checkbox value"

Comment: actually i am not sure what he's asking for now i thought he wanted to do the function he listed, and pass the actual checkbox1 and checkbox2 in.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you ***could*** do it this way... If you ***really*** wanted to

```
onclick="a(document.getElementById('checkbox1'), document.getElementById('checkbox2'))"
```